# How to find the following derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Here is the complete problem but (c) is the part that I am having problems with, I have already solved (a) and (b):

(a) If $t=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$,$-\pi<x<\pi$, sketch a right triangle or use trigonometric identities to show that $$\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\qquad\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$$

(b) Show that $$\cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\qquad\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$

(c) Show that $$dx = \frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$

I am aware that it is relatively simple to obtain the correct result by $x = 2\arctan t$ and if $y = \arctan x$ then  $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ so we obtain the result above. My problem is that I attempted to do it by $x = \arcsin \frac {2t}{1+t^2}$ and knowing that if $y = \arcsin x$ then $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$ I obtained the following result $$ dx = -\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$$ I have reviewed my solution several times and I cannot find an algebraic mistake. In the case that the result is algebraically correct, I am speculating that both results are equivalent because of something that has to do with the restrictions imposed when defining inverse trigonometric functions but I am lost and cannot figure out the connection.

**EDIT**

I understand the mistake now, the restriction of $x \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ needs to be made as dictated by the definition of $\arcsin$ and then $t=\tan(x/2)\in[\tan(-\pi/4),\tan(\pi/4)]=[-1,1]$. Now, my question is the following: when attempting to find $dx$ by $x = 2\arctan t$ we impose the restriction of $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$  because $\arctan t \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ but, doesn't this contradict the restrictions we imposed on $x$ when finding $dx$ by $x = \arcsin \frac {2t}{1+t^2}$?

Comment: I noticed you didn't accept any of the answers for your questions so far. You're supposed to accept one answer to your question if you consider it to be satisfactory.

Comment: There should be a symbol (I don't know what it's called) below the arrow which points downwards located to the left of each answer. You pick your favorite answer and then click on that symbol to accept it.

Comment: @LanceFerd One has to be carefull when taking root of a squared function: $$\sqrt{f^2(x)} = \big|f(x)\big|.$$ See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/278546/19532) for details.

Comment: Note that $\arcsin$ will return an angle in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$; so your formula $x=\arcsin{2t\over 1+t^2}$ is valid only for $t\in[-1,1]$. For $|t|>1$, you'll need a (slightly) different formula.

Comment: @DavidMitra Why does it only work for the range $t \in (-1,1)$? I think that it is the source of my confusion.

Comment: If $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, then $t=\tan(x/2)\in[\tan(-\pi/4),\tan(\pi/4)]=[-1,1]$. If $x$ is not in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, then $|\tan(x/2)|>1$.

Comment: When $|t|>1$, you know that $x\in(\pi/2,\pi]\cup [-\pi  ,-\pi/2)$. In this case $x=\pi-\arcsin{2t\over 1+t^2}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra If we do it by letting $x=\arctan t$, what would the restrictions on $x$ be?

Comment: I meant $x = 2\arctan t $, since $\arctan t$ will only return an angle in $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ does it mean that in this case $ x \in [-\pi,\pi] $? Doesn't this contradict the above restrictions for $x$?

Comment: Setting $x=2\arctan t$ is fine: you have $-\pi< x <\pi\iff -\pi/2<x/2<\pi/2$. Then $2\arctan t$ will give you $x$ back, always.  I'm not sure what you meant about the "above restrictions for $x$"; but, what I said in my earlier comments applied to $\arcsin{2t\over 1+t^2}$.

Comment: I understand now. I was making the mistake of thinking that what you said also applied to $x= 2\arctan t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If
$$
t = \tan(x)
$$
you can use impicit differentiation, i.e.
$$
\frac{d}{dt}t = \frac{d}{dt}\tan\left(\frac{x(t)}{2}\right)
$$
so
$$
1 = \frac{1}{2}\sec^2\left(\frac{x(t)}{2}\right) x'(t),
$$
then
$$
2 \cos^2\left(\frac{x(t)}{2}\right) = x'(t)
$$
and using (a)
$$
2 \cos^2\left(\frac{x(t)}{2}\right) =\frac{2}{1 + t^2} = x'(t)
$$

**EDIT**

The principal branch of $\arcsin \xi$ is defined only when $\xi \in (-1,1)$. Then $\arcsin \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ is defined when $t \in (-1,1)$. Now, let
$$
x = \arcsin \frac{2 t}{1 + t^2}
$$
then
\begin{align}
\frac{d x}{d t} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4 t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}}} \frac{d}{d t}\left\{\frac{2 t}{1+t^2}\right\} = - \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{4 t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}}} \frac{t^2 -1}{(1 + t^2)^2}\\
&= -2 \frac{1+t^2}{\big|t^2 - 1\big|} \frac{t^2 -1}{(1 + t^2)^2}
\end{align}
and given that $t \in (-1,1)$,
$$
\big|t^2 - 1\big| = 1 - t^2
$$
Finally
$$
\frac{d x}{d t} = \frac{2}{1+t^2}
$$

Comment: @GitGud Edited. By the way, if you use `\arcsin x`, you produce $$\arcsin x.$$

Comment: I do not follow why $t \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: @LanceFerd It's the domain of definition for $\arcsin t$, i.e. the range where $\sin x$ is invertible -in the principal branch, that is-.

Comment: What would be restrictions on $x$ and $t$ if we were to do it by $x=2\arctan t$?

Comment: Please, look at my last question to David Mitra above.